# Rails fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, event-handling, fullcalendar

So this is the thing when i add event click in my fullCalendar script in events.js.cofee it crashes with turbolink

SyntaxError: `[stdin]:7:24: reserved word 'function'`

```
<%=javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Now this is my orginal events.js.coffee without adding eventClick

> Note: with this it doesnt crash and works perfectly but my eventClick
>   doesnt do what i want obviously.

```
$(document).ready ->
$("#calendar").fullCalendar(
       header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,agendaDay'
    },
       events: '/events.json'

)
```

This is my `Javascript` with `eventClick`:

```
$(document).ready ->
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
       eventClick: function(event) {
            var modal = $("#modal");
            modal.find(".modal-title").html(event.title);
            modal.modal();
          },
       header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,agendaDay'
    },
       events: '/events.json'

)
```

With this code it does not work. Why is that?

> Note: In case you need to know what modal is.

```
<div class="modal" role="dialog" id="modal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is of function keyword change your js as :

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar
    header:
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,agendaDay'

    events: '/events.json'
    eventClick: (event, jsEvent) ->
       var modal = $("#modal");
       modal.find(".modal-title").html(event.title);
       modal.modal();
  return
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: oh Still you are getting same issue, this works for me.

Comment: fixed, it was CoffeScript sintax errors, i changed the sintax to Js and the type of file to .js